# Windows 7 x64 Startup repair infinite loop

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, boot

Last night my windows PC took a significantly longer than normal to shut down and appeared slower than usual this morning (slow start-up, hanging). After a reboot, it appears I'm not longer able to get in to windows, and am instead provided with the start-up repair system. This doesn't seem to do anything to fix the problem on its own, and any subsequent reboots simply end up back in start-up repair.

I've so far attempted the following:

1) I've tried restoring the registry hive manually [(Source)](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/139576-startup-repair-infinite-loop-recovery.html). This lead to at least getting rid of the start-up repair loop, but ultimately ends in an instant blue screen and reboot after "starting windows". I've since restored the registry to its original state.

2) I've tried chkdsk /f on my drive [(Source)](https://neosmart.net/wiki/startup-repair-infinite-loop/). This has since hanged and I haven't done anything since. The output of this is below.

```
C:\>chkdsk D: /f
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Cannot lock current drive.

Chkdsk cannot run because the volume is in use b another process. Chkdsk may run if this volume is dismounted first.
ALL OPENED HANDLES TO THIS VOLUME WOULD THEN BE INVALID.
Would you like to force a dismount on this volume? (Y/N) y
Volume dismounted. All opened handles to this volume are now invalid.

CHKDSK is verifying files (stage 1 of 3)...
    482048 file records processed.
File verification completed.
    1507 large file records processed.
    0 bad file records processed.
    2 EA records processed.
    61 reparse records processed.
CHKDSK is verifying indexes (stage 2 of 3)...
    626432 index entries processed.
Index verification completed.
    0 unindexed files scanned.
    0 unindexed files recovered.
CHKDSK is verifying security descriptors (stage 3 of 3)...
    482048 file SDs/SIDs processed.
Insufficient disk space to fix the security descriptors data stream.
Insufficient disk space to fix the security descriptors data stream.
Insufficient disk space to fix the security descriptors data stream.
Security descriptor verification completed.
    72193 data files processed.
CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
    35555160 USN bytes processed.
Usn Journal verification completed.
Failed to transfer logged messages to the event log with status 50.
```

Comment: Based on the behavior is sounds like you have a HDD failure.  I would clone the drive if its possible restore the image to a new hdd.

Comment: @Ramhound would you suggest running a SMART test on the drive? It's less than a year old and has a 5 year warranty, I'll at least be able to get it replaced.

Comment: It can't hurt the drive.  Just be warned even if it passes those S.M.A.R.T tests does not mean there isn't a problem thats not being detected.

Comment: if the drive is fine, I'd just re-install windows.